# Cannot relocate svn working copy

Tags: svn

Recently I was forced to move my development server with installed `subversion` version control server on it to new location and and therefore the server gained new `IP` address. The location of repository physically on disk is `/srv/svn_firmAA/project1`. Old `subversion` server repository address is `svn://192.168.0.2:10000/srv/svn_firmAA/project1`. Now, the new `subversion` server repository address is `svn://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10000/srv/svn_firmAA/project1` and I tried to `relocate` working copy to new `IP` with:
`svn switch --relocate svn://192.168.0.2:10000/srv/svn_firmAA/project1 svn://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10000/srv/svn_firmAA/project1`
and I get following error:

```
svn: E155024: Invalid source URL prefix: 'svn://192.168.0.2:10000/srv/svn_firmAA/project1' (does not overlap target's URL 'svn://192.168.0.2:10000')
```

Why?

Here is working copy `svn info` output:

```
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: /home/user/Projects/working_copy
URL: svn://192.168.0.2:10000
Relative URL: ^/
Repository Root: svn://192.168.0.2:10000
Repository UUID: 54d40152-b288-42d4-b588-490a5dcf01bf
Revision: 579
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: user
Last Changed Rev: 579
Last Changed Date: 2015-12-30 11:06:19 +0100 (sre, 30 dec 2015)
```

Comment: Can you try `svn info new_url` ?

Comment: It's seems like your new url is not working

Comment: @Y.N hmm, I am getting **Connection timeout error**:  
`svn: E000110: Unable to connect to a repository at URL svn://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10000/srv/svn_firmAA/project1
svn: E000110: Can't connect to host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx': Connection timed out`
However, I can connect to repository remotely using `TortoiseSVN` on **Windows**, it does not work from my **Linux workstation**. I think ports are setup correctly.  `Subversion` server listens on port `10000` for incoming connection, I've checked on server (here is `htop` line):
`/usr/bin/svnserve -d --listen-port=10000 -r /srv/svn_firmAA/project1/`

Comment: You have try from several computers? Their network connections are same? Svn protocol is not proxy safe.

Comment: @Y.N I have workstation with installed `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS` and laptop with installed `MS Windows 7 Ultimate` and from laptop I've managed to relocate its working copy with `TortoiseSVN` but I cannot relocate working copy from `Linux` workstation. The working copy on workstation is the "main code" and I need to relocate it to (now) remote server with new IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solve problem:

1. Incoming port was wrong (port `20000` is forwarded to port `10000` on server)
2. `svn switch --relocate` parameters must **NOT INCLUDE** repository paths:

   svn switch --relocate svn://192.168.0.2:10000 svn://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20000

Now it works perfectly!